# Simple Stacked Barchart using VegaLite with Text Labels

Tags: bar-chart, data-visualization, vega-lite

I'm having an issue labeling my barchart.  I would like the total number of backers to be labeled at the right handside of each bar. Not the sum of "US Backers" and "Backers from Other Countries" individually as shown.

The dataset I'm using shows the most popular categories on the Kickstarter project website, and I have highlighted projects launched in the USA to show the popularity of the website in the States as compared to worldwide.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuV6V.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taramcgirl/InfoVisProject/master/graphone.csv",
    "format": {
      "type": "csv"
    }
  },

  "title": {
    "text": "Total Backers per Category",
    "anchor": "middle",
    "fontSize":24
  },
   "width":400,
    "height":400,
    "mark": {
      "type": "bar", 
      "cornerRadiusEnd": 4
      },
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
         "axis": {
          "title": "Number of Backers",
          "labelFontSize":10, 
          "titleFontSize":15
          },
          "field" : "Backers",
          "type" :  "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
      "y": {
        "axis": {
        "title": "Category",
        "labelFontSize":10, 
        "titleFontSize":15
        },
        "field":"Main_Category",
        "type" : "nominal",
        "sort": "-x"
      },
      "color": {
        "field": "USA or ELSEWHERE", 
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale": {
          "domain":["US","Other"], 
          "range": ["#8101FA", "#00C7A9"]
          }
        },
      "opacity": {
          "value" : 0.5
      }
    },
    "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
    }, {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "bottom",
        "stroke":"black",
        "dx": 3,
        "fontSize": 9,
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "stack":"false" 
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Backers", 
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "stack": "true"          
        }

    }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make it such that the color encoding only applies to the bar layer, you'll get the desired outcome. With a bit of cleanup of redundant & invalid parameters, the result looks like this: ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJFYAnMdlwFiZUifQB3BszbtWsZCfjK8yJXjpeqKS6dqjwTGakAJJKAGbcAGqMsAAKJtxyyPB4pBiwPiak1HaEiACMAbAUkBoAvupGeMxiyBYGhpA+AB54FpAAKty6YmAAQujwANYesGCEHmAAwjo03CYAnmoaRuhKSGt9qIyami1bhlDxfgDKjABerTgATNJ1DVD2xywW0gAMv+9IChGNR8D9-oDfF5NIwlNQ2tsoF0ERcdl1kijUY1mo8oAA5ViodgLbixMYTaYmWDnLFQMToYliABi3luDwsZQBiIunRxLJu91xZQArNywPUxZAEOgzvpIJpuBhYRYANoAsCc-5a34AXQlWMgsUYyDEmj64ymMxpPLw63mfQAjqxdk1dE0qNaOuhqMVhD4+rBCTULvqOpt9JL0OjqXLXbKoMsfNQ1ptVHSGSb+Xg2UL1by8C0szmOcLQzyjSazThIABZdCwgD6idWG09jTtuMgSkVsJlbagihMvWrImRiNqbw0kHp6w8qsR7R5GBMkzanQ7fXY6BMaigXhMSg8ACV0DC3ABRJRVsDSMsdKHcGFwzEGrxiA4R2kdCumvoAVWuABBMA1jAc8ABlrnPAB1AAJc8j3PfsbQ3atuyOJQ+3eL8pXgGVcWAeVFXrFQcBVSAAN3SAAHkWDnHU00gOw4VxciAGIAA5OTKJlAKotj-kWAB2QCAE5ID1MUIDvHluEICZmHDMBCIoGVWFxX46FLMUJxDbDlMlZdV0-Wl13tatul6fSeRlEFSLpZBYisqSoC3dwJEPQ5jlOVprI6fJ0mmTd6SmZCtGRHAAGY-KMK5s0FCxRJ0vzIAfJ94RMg1LLXH9r0gC1KWpRjbXMqAnRdZgdEYD1GO9X1aH9atA1QSBdNRNrpI0HUQFqIA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taramcgirl/InfoVisProject/master/graph1.csv"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Total Backers per Category",
    "anchor": "middle",
    "fontSize": 24
  },
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "axis": {
        "title": "Number of Backers",
        "labelFontSize": 10,
        "titleFontSize": 15
      },
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 10000000]},
      "field": "Backers",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum"
    },
    "y": {
      "axis": {"title": "Category", "labelFontSize": 10, "titleFontSize": 15},
      "field": "Main_Category",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": "-x"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "cornerRadiusEnd": 4},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "USA or ELSEWHERE",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"domain": ["US", "Other"], "range": ["#8101FA", "#00C7A9"]}
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "stroke": "black",
        "dx": 3,
        "fontSize": 9
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "Backers", "type": "quantitative", "aggregate": "sum"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway of making the text label the total of the bar and not the two individual bars?